# AngularJS - Passing JSON data to Angular module

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

How to pass a JSON data to Angular module.
This is my code

```
<div ng-init="init({{post.name}})">
```

Comment: find working http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15925/

Comment: if post.name is a JSON then you can simply pass to the init method <div ng-init="init(post.name)">

Comment: Can I pass a single data @Janty @neda?

`[{"name":"John","age":"21"},
{"name":"Mike","age":"23"}]`

Example : {{post.name}} = "John"

Comment: Yes, I have passed single data in jsfiddle. What would you like to pass ? Provide me the sample. I will try to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-init="init({name: post.name})">
```

or if you want to pass all data

```
<div ng-init="init(post)">
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15925/)